# What are lines like `<%= className %>` in CSS called?

Tags: php, css, drupal

I am trying to fix a problem on a site and have a file that contains CSS like:

```
<%= className %>:before {
  font-family: "<%= fontName %>";
}
```

Obviously these are variables, but I'm not sure how/where they are set.

I'm not sure what these are technically called so I cannot Google them to learn more. Would anyone know what these are called?

EDIT:

I found this line at the bottom of the code:

```
<% _.each(glyphs, function(glyph) { %>.<%= className %>--<%= glyph.name %>:before { content: "\<%= glyph.unicode[0].charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase() %>" }
<% }); %>
```

I'm guessing this is looping through and creating the vars.

Comment: What's parsing the css? My first guess was SSI, but that uses <!-- syntax for variables, and wouldn't have been run on css anyway. I assume then that this css is embedded, not in a .css file, right?

Comment: Would need some more information to answer this one. Do the files have any extension apart from .css? Is there a build chain in place that’s failing?

Comment: @Lizardx this CSS is an external .css file, added separately to the man one compiled from sass.

Comment: @RobinWhittleton no the file is just a .css. I'm not sure what you mean by build chain, but there are no errors appearing in the console.

Comment: looks like syntax for JSPs (as in Java Server Pages) - How is it being invoked?  - **btw**, they are called scriptlets in JSP lingo

Comment: @ochi it's just being called in the head like any other .css file (AFAIK)

Comment: is the file you are looking at an HTML file?

Comment: where is that extra code located, in the css file, at the bottom? It's too hard to guess, you have to do some more looking then you can modify your question to better reflect the actual question.

Comment: @Lizardx it was located last in the file, at the very bottom

Comment: While I'm not going to add another downvote to this question, since it was actually sort of interesting in weird way, you should take more care in posting questions, and start listing actual relevant context, like this being a drupal file, that is php parsed, and where exactly the file contents appear, and how. People should not have to ask anyone, particularly not someone with a fair number of reputation points, for this information on an initial posting. Too much information is far better than no information, as a general rule when posting questions.

Comment: @Lizardx Yeah, I usually do. Honestly thought someone would just reply 'Oh, those are called XXX'. Thought it was more simple then what it was.

I'll fill out the total answer later, but this didn't have anything to do with PHP or Drupal, but rather Gulp.

Comment: Another option, lol.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's ASP, not positive, but ASP used <% for code start/end. I'd further assume it's an embedded CSS. Though asp could be run on CSS like php could if you wanted. Old ASP, not .net. Could be another language, depends.  As someone else noted, it's not definitely ASP,  it's just some server side scripting like ASP, which shares that <%. You can figure out what it is probably by looking at what is including that css file.

NOTE: further information suggests it's internal Drupal parsing delimiters, which tell drupal's php logic to insert the value of that variable name into that field.

I don't know if I'd say those are 'called' anything, they are just how the server side language is told to output whatever data or events or functions are between those start/end markers. In PHP it's

```
<?php.....?>
```

for example.

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_introduction.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<%
response.write("My first ASP script!")
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically it's not possible to answer fully the question without knowing what is using that css file, is it being included in a CMS for example? which would then be ASP based, or whatever language that is. Generally you would not see that in a standard css file, but if that file is used as an include to something else that is generating a master css file, then that something else could be parsing the css and inserting values in those areas that are delineated by <%... markers %>

Assuming the ASP syntax is the same as PHP's, that's a short cut for printing out the variable value. <%= that is, means, print this to the page. I haven't touched ASP for over a decade, but that's roughly what it is I believe.

But because that variable name looks like it's supposed to be assigned, I'd guess that this css file is actually an include that the language inserts values into before using, either outputting that modified file data as a css file, or serving the css as embedded into the page.

It could be internal triggers for a PHP page, for example. That is, a php page can request the CSS file, then parse it using the <% delineators, and the = would serve the same function it usually does, in php's case, print it to the page, or file contents in this case.

If memory serves, the specific syntax of ?> or %> type code markers can be set on the server, but the norm in php is ?>. You'll need more details to really figure it out. What are the drupal files themselves started with?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is being included in a Drupal 7 CMS, which, as far as I know, is PHP based. There is a 'master' .css file which is compiled from other .scss files, but this is added seperately to the head.

Comment: This would then be a drupal specific question I believe. Since drupal is php it's probably building embedded css from that file, or building a css file from that file, to output to users.

Comment: If this css is 'added separately to the head', or <head> as css, embedded, you have your answer, this css is a file that is included when drupal builds its page, and is embedded in the page head after undergoing parsing of variables included in the css file. So this really isn't a css file, it's the raw material to create the css. That's how it looks to me from what you are saying anyway.